# cross domain htaccess config

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to route

http://domain.fr/subpage

to

http://domain.com/fr/subpage

using htaccess.
Any ideas how?

All the small config elements of .htaceess are driving me batty on this cold Monday morning.

Comment: I should add that both domains are on the same server and working just fine :)

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.fr/subpage[nc]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://domain.com/fr/subpage [r=301,nc]

Gives a 404?

Comment: Gothere in the end


[code]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.fr$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} subnavfolder
#RewriteRule ^.*$ http://domain.com/fr/subnavfolder [R=301,L][/code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subpage[/]?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/fr/subpage [R=301,L]
```

Those rules will check if the domain is `domain.fr` **and** if the URI is `/subpage` or `/subpage/` and will then redirect with statuscode 301 (permantly moved) to the actual address you wish.